# How can I access the Mongoose Model from inside of a statics function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to define a `statics` function called `convertFromCartItems` that takes an array of models of type `CartItem`, creates an array of models of type `OrderItem`, and then inserts them in a single operation using MongoDB's `insertMany()`.  My current function for creating the `Order` from the `Cart` (the parent models that the `OrderItem` and `CartItem` respectively point to) looks like this:

```
  schema.statics.convertFromCart = function (cart, shipping, then, unless) {
    let order = new this()
    order._cart = cart
    order.firstName = shipping.firstName
    order.lastName = shipping.lastName
    order.email = shipping.email
    order.address = shipping.address
    order.addressCity = shipping.addressCity
    order.addressPostalCode = shipping.addressPostalCode
    order.addressRegionCode = shipping.addressRegionCode
    order.addressCountryCode = shipping.addressCountryCode

    order.save((err, thing) => {
      if (!err && thing) {
        then(thing)
      } else {
        unless(err)
      }
    })
  }
```

This function calls `.save()` by itself so to invoke it I have a line similar to this:

```
models.Order.convertFromCart(cart, shipping, (order) => {
  // Do something with the newly created 'Order'
})
```

However in Mongoose (and really MongoDB) `insertMany()` is defined on the model and not the instance, so what I want to do is something like this:

```
schema.statics.convertFromCartItems = function (order, items, then unless) {
  let orderItems = []
  items.forEach((item) => {
    let orderItem = this()
    orderItem._item = item
    orderItem._order = order
    orderItem.quantity = item.quantity
    orderItem.subscribed = item.subscribed
    orderItem.name = item._item._product.name
    orderItem.variation = item._item.variation
    orderItem.price = item._item.price
    orderItem.image = item._item._product.image
    orderItem.created = item.created
    orderItem.updated = item.update
    orderItems.push(orderItem)
  })
  // code I want to use
  OrderItemSchema.insertMany(orderItems, funciton (err, things) {
    if (!err && things) {
      then(things)
    } else {
      unless(err)
    }
  })
}
```

However while inside this `statics.convertFromCartItems` function, `OrderItemSchema` doesn't yet exist.  Mongoose uses some `this` trickery to let me create an instance of the model by calling `this()` but `this.insertMany()` or `this().insertMany()` do not work (as `insertMany()` is on the model and not an instance).  The current workarround is to return the array and then call `models.OrderItem.insertMany()` for the items outside of this function.  Any ideas of how I can make this function insert itself?

If it helps to understand what I'm after here is a basic overview of these two models. I have a model that represents an item in a shopping cart (`CartItem`) and I'm trying to take an array of these and create an array of lines in a completed order (`OrderItem`) (this is similar to the [Double-entry bookkeeping system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-entry_bookkeeping_system) allowing a completed order to have a snapshot of the data at the time the order was received while the `CartItem` can point to the current definition of things like the product's name and price).

Comment: Looks like you want an "instance" `method` instead of `statics`. Using `statics` is just like a `static` declaration on a class in certain other language implementations ( hence the name ) and works more like a "constructor" method as opposed to instance data. If you want "what is currently in the loaded docment" then you want `method` instead.

Comment: But a `method` would represent a single instance of a model, here I am building an array of these models and calling the static function `insertMany` (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany)

Comment: `let order = new this()` and `order.firstName = shipping.firstName`. That's from "your" code in the question you are asking. That's "instance" data.

Comment: Ah I see, but that code is inside the `forEach()` block to be appended onto an array `let orderItems = []` and the whole array is passed to `insertMany`, this is different than creating an instance and telling mongoose to save it (it didn't use to be, but a recent update to MongoDB introduced a single operation to batch insert an array with a single callback.  I can accept if I'm misusing this function (I'm not an expert in mongoDB) but it is exactly the funciton I need to batch insert, it's not available on an instance of a mongoose model